# /boot partition full on Fedora

Tags: boot, partitioning, filesystems, fedora, kernel

when I start system, I get an error message that `/boot` is full, also when I try `dnf upgrade`, I get a `Transaction test error` that says that `kernel-core-5.5.10-200.fc31.x86_64` needs 38 MB in `/boot`. 
I already used `sudo dnf remove <old kernels>` twice because `rpm -qa kernel` showed me three different kernels, so I left only the one I am using now. 
I tried to use `package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2` but for some reason it tells me that `--oldkernels` option isn't available:
`package-cleanup has to be executed with one of the options: --dupes, --leaves, --orphans, --problems or --cleandupes`.

This is my `ls -Shla /boot`:

```
total 218M
-rw-------.  1 root root  80M 03-16 01:07 initramfs-0-rescue-4251ae127a3e4220b94ebab6645dba6c.img
-rw-------.  1 root root  31M 03-16 01:08 initramfs-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64.img
-rw-------.  1 root root  29M 03-19 09:06 initramfs-5.5.9-200.fc31.x86_64.img
-rw-------.  1 root root  27M 03-16 04:40 initramfs-5.5.8-200.fc31.x86_64.img
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  11M 03-05 22:42 vmlinuz-5.5.8-200.fc31.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  11M 03-12 15:10 vmlinuz-5.5.9-200.fc31.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 8,9M 03-16 01:08 vmlinuz-0-rescue-4251ae127a3e4220b94ebab6645dba6c
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 8,9M 10-21 21:34 vmlinuz-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64
-rw-------.  1 root root 4,9M 03-12 15:09 System.map-5.5.9-200.fc31.x86_64
-rw-------.  1 root root 4,9M 03-05 22:42 System.map-5.5.8-200.fc31.x86_64
-rw-------.  1 root root 4,3M 10-21 21:33 System.map-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 213K 03-05 22:42 config-5.5.8-200.fc31.x86_64
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 213K 03-12 15:09 config-5.5.9-200.fc31.x86_64
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 209K 10-21 21:33 config-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 181K 2019-08-02  elf-memtest86+-5.01
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 179K 2019-08-02  memtest86+-5.01
drwx------.  6 root root  16K 1970-01-01  efi
drwx------.  2 root root  12K 03-16 01:05 lost+found
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root 4,0K 03-16 05:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 3,0K 10-24 01:12 extlinux
dr-xr-xr-x.  7 root root 1,0K 03-19 09:06 .
drwx------.  3 root root 1,0K 01-13 18:14 grub2
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 1,0K 03-16 01:07 loader
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  166 10-21 21:30 .vmlinuz-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64.hmac
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  166 03-05 22:40 .vmlinuz-5.5.8-200.fc31.x86_64.hmac
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  166 03-12 15:07 .vmlinuz-5.5.9-200.fc31.x86_64.hmac
```

In addition, when I was assigning space for `/boot` partition during installation, I set it to 250 MiB.
How should I solve it? Should I delete some of these files, use some magic command or maybe something else?

Comment: Removing the rescue files should give you breathing space.  Later, try to extend the boot partition but it's a good idea to clean it now and then.

Comment: Should I just remove them using a rm command? Aren't there any files that depends on them?

Comment: Also, can I remove files with old kernel names? Like initramfs-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64.img, vmlinuz-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64, System.map-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64, config-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64 and .vmlinuz-5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64.hmac.

Comment: Only remove enough to permit the kernel upgrade.  After upgrade, continue cleaning.  I always keep the current and one less recent kernel, as fallback.  If you're not certain, have a rescue stick or cd/dvd ready.

Comment: @Ropoocha use your distribution's tools to remove software. E.g. on Fedora `rpm -qf filename` tells you the package a file belongs to, `dnf erase package` deletes it. Erase old, unused kernels first. Perhaps check the configuration to keep less of them around?

Comment: No need to remove your rescue files, the Fedora community has a perfect answer: https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/boot-nearly-full-how-to-free-space/73206